# Não consigo chamar a função javascript por um botão

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom dia, estou com um problema em minha pagina.

Criei um Form com um campo para comentário. Ao clicar no botão ele "deveria" chamar a função mas não chama.

```js
function gravaobs(pag_pedido, obs_boleto, stats)
            {
                if (obs_boleto.length == 0)
                {
                    alert('Por favor, preencha a observação');
                    document.formobs.observacao.focus();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    var param = {'pag_pedido': pag_pedido, 'obs_boleto': obs_boleto, 'status': stats};
                    OpenWindowWithPost('tela_de_tratamento.php', '', 'NewFile1', param);
                }
            }
```

```html
<form id="formobs" name="formobs">
                                        <table style='width: 1220px;'>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align='center' style='padding:5px 0 10px 0; font: 12pt Trebuchet MS; color: #00471A; margin:0 auto;'>&nbsp;Inserir Obs.:</td>
                                                <td align='center' style='padding:5px 0 10px 0; font: 12pt Trebuchet MS; color: #00471A; margin:0 auto;'><input style='width: 975px;' id='observacao' name='observacao' type='text' maxlength='250' tabindex='4' size='137'/></td>
                                                <td style='font-size:14px; text-align:left;'><br/></td>
                                                <td align='center'><p class='botao'><a href='#' title='Gerar' onclick="javascript:gravaobs(<?php print $pag_pedido; ?>, document.formobs.observacao.value, <?php print $status; ?>);"></a></p></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </form>
```

Todos as variáveis estão normais e até mesmo (colocando php echo variaveis) elas aparecem normal, mas não sei porque não funciona

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Escreve `onClick` tudo com letra pequena. Assim: `onclick`

Comment: Ja tentei, e não obtive resultado

Comment: Essa função esta dentro da tag <head> <script> e o Browser não da nenhum erro, no link da pagina aparece o # apos o nome da pagina mas nada acontece, nem a mensagem caso o campo esteja vazio.
A tela no caso é só o campo para digitar e uma imagem de um botão, nada de mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que nunca é sensato tentar colar strings à mão — nesse exemplo, você tem que se preocupar com o escaping do HTML mas também com o escaping do JavaScript. Eu acho que é mais seguro fazer isso

```
<a href="#" title="Gerar" data-pag-pedido="<?= htmlspecialchars($pag_pedido) ?>" data-status="<?= htmlspecialchars($status) ?>" onclick="javascript:gravaobs(this.dataset.pagPedido, document.formobs.observacao.value, this.dataset.status)">
```

que funciona no IE 11+, ou use `this.getAttribute('data-pag-pedido')` no lugar de `this.dataset.pagPedido` (idem pro `status`) se você precisar dar suporte a IE 8+.

(talvez você precise colocar `; return false` no final do `onclick`, pra evitar que a tela role para o começo)

Comment: Direto e reto, funciona cara, VALEU!